# storing the browser title derived from selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm a noob in selenium. I'm choosing python to learn automation. Here's my question. I have been trying to do the following things.

1. Get Page Title name and Title length
2. Print Page Title and Title length on IDLE Console/any console.
3. Get Page URL and URL length
4. Print URL and URL length on the IDLE Console/any console.
5. Refresh current page
6. Get Page Source (HTML Source code) and Page Source length

For all of these I know I can get the web driver bindings from the documentation. But I'm confused how to store these into data types. I have seen answers in java but not in python. Python experts can you help me out. Here's the code I've been trying.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get("http://www.google.com") # Load page
curre = browser.current_url
print curre #this gives an error.
```

Comment: Please add the error you get to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code works, I have tested it (on Python 2.7):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://www.google.com") # Load page

# 1 & 2 
title = browser.title
print title, len(title)

# 3 & 4
curre = browser.current_url
print curre, len(curre)

#5
browser.refresh()

#6
page_source = browser.page_source
print page_source, len(page_source)
```

Comment: when i'm trying to compile it says "missing parenthesis in call to print". Print usually works in idle but in this specific program print isn't working... Can you give any suggestions ??

Comment: Thanks man... I found the error It was because of syntax of python versions... I was earlier on python 2.7 now i just upgraded to python 3. So there's seems to be some syntax change.. Thanks for your help ...

Comment: can you point me out a source from where you got these web driver bindings. !! - thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the official [reference documentation](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). The delay (point #0) comes from the settings I have in my BDD setup with [Behave](http://pythonhosted.org/behave/)